# Exit status 255 when trying to do npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

When I try to run npm start I am facing this issue again and again with status code 255.
Things I have tried till now:

1. Uninstalled,removed node modules and package.json file and reinstalled still same issue.
2. Changed the package.json file
3. Removed webpack-dev-server and reinstalled
4. There is no application running on port 3000

I have included screenshots of log file and errors below:

[image: npm-start-error]
[image: log file]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now I had a dependency issue with `webpack-dev-server`. 
I removed all `node modules`, `package-lock.json`, and `webpack-dev-server` dependencies from `package.json` and did the npm install again. It works fine now.

Comment: Sir I tried to accept the answer and close but it shows I can do that only after two days. And yeah I tried for almost half a day and then posted the question.

Comment: Hi Sai, no one is Sir here, Its good you got the solution, once i was just same like you and getting such comments So, I did the same, Have a Great Day, Keep coding contributing